# Randomly changing text in django base template

Tags: django, templates, bootstrap-5

I have just started learning Django. Currently I am building project with several apps. I have `templates` folder at the project level which contains `base.html`. This file contains Bootstrap5 elements `Navbar` and `Card` (quote). At the app level I also have `templates` folder that contains several html files. All of them extends `base.html` from project level. I would like to randomly change the text in quote Card, so every time when bowser render template from app level it displays new quote. I have Model named `Quotes` at the app level and I can use `quote=Quotes.objects.all(?).first()` to select random entry. But I have no idea how to connect to the `base.html`. Could you give me a hint how to solve my problem?

```html
<!--templates/base.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'judokas:home' %}">Treneri</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'judokas:home' %}">Takmicari</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled">Statistika</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Quote-->
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Quote
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>{% block quote %}
              {% endblock %}</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer">Jigoro Kano in <cite title="Source Title">https://www.azquotes.com</cite></footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock  %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context processors are perfect for that job. You can pass a context (like in regular views), but it can be used by any template.

```
def get_random_quote(request):
    return {
        "random_quote": Quotes.objects.all(?).first(),
    }
```

Then in template:

```
{{ random_quote }}
```

[Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: Thank you very much for point me in the right direction. I create file `context_processors.py` at the level of the app and put context processor function inside and update `settings.py` file at project level by adding `my_app.context_processors.get_random.quote`. And the Django magic did the rest job!

Comment: Awesome! :) If an answer is a solution, then it should be selected as the correct answer.